# can you view your own deleted questions?

Tags: support

Is it possible to find/view your own deleted questions? I'm looking for a question I asked about Jonathan Edwards view of Adam. Apparently its been deleted. Is there any way I can view it? I quoted a particular section from his book "Preservative Against Socinianism" and I'm looking for that quote; don't want to have to crack open the book and search for it when it should be around already.

Comment: I think you should be able to if you scroll through [all of your questions](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/10507/david-brainerd?tab=questions&sort=votes).  In the meantime, is [this](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30934/do-evangelicals-still-believe-as-jonathan-edwards-did-that-adam-was-created-wi) the one you're looking for?

Comment: @David Stratton, That's the one. I don't get any kind of scroll.  When I go to my questions is just shows 22 questions, not button for "more" or anything.

Comment: Next time edit your questions as/when prompted to fix issues and they won't end up deleted in the first place! The garbage collection system auto-deleted that particular post because it was closed, not up-voted, and no edits were made. However it looks like it really didn't need much work. I just edited it to be much more answerable, hopefully that will dot the trick.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the answer is [you can only see them if you have a link to them already, but they won't show up in your questions queue until you hit 10k reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

> Since June 2013, deleted questions and answers that were posted in the
>   past 60 days, can be seen using the "deleted recent questions" and
>   "deleted recent answers" links on the questions and answers tabs in
>   your user profile.
>
> For older posts: as of 23/Apr/2013 you can view your own deleted
>   questions if you already have a link to them, but they still aren't
>   linked from the user profiles (not even just for you). Nor do you see
>   inbox notifications for comments on them if you come back a few hours
>   later. You have to have thought to bookmark your question, or you have
>   to go digging for it in your browser history.

In the meantime, feel free to ping us in chat if you need to find an older question or answer of yours that has been deleted.